# PhpStorm IDE. Collapse custom/debug code

Tags: debugging, ide, phpstorm

Is it possible to collapse custom code in PhpStorm?
Like if you set in settings pattern:

`[START]$this->debugOutput(*)[END]`

The concept is to hide debug code after developing finished.
In example below all lines with `$this->debugOutput` should be hidden

```
class Foo {


    public function bar()
    {

        $x = 1 + 2;

        $this->debugOutput($x);

        $y = 3 + 3;

        $z = 5 + 5;

        $this->debugOutput($y);
        $this->debugOutput($z);
    }

    public function debugOutput($msg, $dump = false)
    {

        if($this->config->debug !== true){
            return;
        }

        @ob_end_flush();
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_start();

        if($dump){
            var_dump($msg);
        } else {
            echo $msg . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have such code collapsed automatically via settings/matching pattern.

But you can surround such code with [custom folding blocks](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/) -- the folding state will be remembered when opening next time and if opened first time it also will be collapsed (thanks to `defaultstate="collapsed"` part).

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="My debug code description">
... debug code here
//</editor-fold>
```

[image]

---

Other than that: only by manually folding selection (e.g. make selection and then `Code | Folding | Fold Selection / Remove region`) -- but I'm not sure if it will survive until next session (IDE restart) since there will be no folding comments added.