# Prettier in WebStorm: Functions get unfolded

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, prettier, jsprettier

When I **run Prettier** all functions got **unfolded**. I have a large component which I would like to stay folded.

Is there any way to prevent this?

```js
const calcPrintBalance = function (account) {
  account.balance = account.movements.reduce((acc, mov) => acc + mov, 0);
  labelBalance.textContent = `${account.balance} EUR`;
};
```

I would like them to stay like this:

```js
const calcPrintBalance = function (account) {...};
```

Comment: The unfolding is done by the IDE and not Prettier itself. The IDE has your file opened in the Editor... and it detects changes after Prettier reformats the file on save. Seems to be a bug -- most likely this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54228

Comment: There is a workaround (have not tested in the JavaScript files but should work fine). It's not exactly the same, but better than nothing. Sadly it requires adding a code folding comments: one line at the start of the block and one at the end. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733813/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/76016008/783119 (they are about PHP but the idea is exactly the same)

Comment: BTW -- if you set up the default folding state (applies at the file opening) -- will it be remembered after Prettier reformat? `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding` -- see if this can be of any help.